# Asp Net Core 3.1. UseExceptionHandler does not handle exceptions

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I want to globally handle exceptions with UseExceptionHandle and redirect  users to the custom error page in production environment. I found that when calling the asynchronous controller action method redirection occurs in a predictable way. But a synchronous action call causes an exception to be thrown and the application stopped.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {            
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseStatusCodePages();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();            
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();          
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {              
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");               
            });
        }
```

For testing, I throw an exception in synchronous and asynchronous action.

```
public async  Task<ViewResult> Index(string user)
        {
           throw new Exception("My Custom Exception");
        }

public ViewResult Index(string user)
        {
            throw new Exception("My Custom Exception");
        }
```

What could be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Could you please tell me which asp.net core version you have used now? 2.1 or 3.1? Do you have a error controller? Could you please post the error controller related codes? I have created a test demo on my side. All of the two method is working well.

Comment: Brando Zhang thank you for your response! Stupid error on my part - when running in debug mode(F5), exceptions are not handled using UseExceptionHandler.